# How do I turn this recursion into tail recursion?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, tail-recursion

With given array on unique numbers which are always greater than 0 I need to find all possible unique combinations of those numbers that are equal to a certain number when summed.

For example, `getNumberComponents([7, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 8, 1], 8)` should return

`[ [ 7, 1 ], [ 4, 3, 1 ], [ 3, 5 ], [ 2, 5, 1 ], [ 2, 6 ], [ 8 ] ]` because sum of all numbers in every subarray equals `8`.

My solution:

```
function getNumberComponents(numArray, number) {
    const arrayLength = numArray.length;
    const allVariants = [];

    function findComponents(currentIndex = 0, currentVariant = []) {
        while (currentIndex < arrayLength) {
            const currentElement = numArray[currentIndex];

            const currentSum = currentVariant.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);

            const sumWithCurrent = currentSum + currentElement;

            if (sumWithCurrent === number) {
        allVariants.push([...currentVariant, currentElement]);
            }

            currentIndex++;

            if (sumWithCurrent < number) {
                findComponents(currentIndex, [...currentVariant, currentElement]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    findComponents();
    
    return allVariants;
}
```

But I wonder if it's possible to use tail recursion for that? I have no idea how to turn my solution into tail recursion.

Comment: It is possible; in fact, it is possible to do without *any* recursion.

Comment: I also implemented the same thing but with iterations. But now I need a tail recursion version of the script

Comment: @queques Well if you have a `loop` you can easily change it to tailrecursion by replacing it with a function where ALL the variables that can change are bound variables and instead of break/end of block you recurse.

Comment: but using tail recusrion you should always return something. But what should I return?
If I return a new element like returning 1 for [2, 5] to make it equal 8, then there's gonna be some problem. If I react, let's say, element 6 that will make [2, 5] equal 13 then what do I return? If I return undefined or nothing then I will have [2, 5, undefined]

Comment: Return all of the variants found.

Comment: @ScottHunter still don't get it. Could you please show in code?

Comment: If you pass a list of the variants found *so far* in each recursive call (adding the new ones as you find them), then the end of the tail recursion will have all of the variants, and can just return that.

Answer (score 2):

To make this tail recursive, you could:

- Keep track of all **indices** that were selected to arrive at the current sum. That way you can easily replace a selected index with the successor index.
- In each execution of the function get the "next" combination of indices. This could be done as follows:

  - If the sum has not been achieved yet, add the index the follows immediately after the most recently selected index, and adjust the sum
  - If the sum has achieved or exceeded, remove the most recently selected index, and then add the successor index instead, and adjust the sum
  - If there is no successor index, then forget about this index and replace the previous one in the list, again adjusting the sum
  - If there are no more entries in the list of indices, then all is done.
- Instead of accumulating a sum, you could also *decrease* the `number` that you pass to recursion -- saving one variable.
- Make the function *return* the array with all variants, so there is no need for an inner function, nor any action that *follows* the function call.

Here is an impementation:

```js
function getNumberComponents(numArray, number, selectedIndices=[], allVariants=[]) {
    let i = selectedIndices.at(-1)??-1;
    if (number < 0) { // Sum is too large. There's no use to adding more
        i = numArray.length; // Force the while-condition to be true
    } else if (number == 0) { // Bingo
        allVariants.push(selectedIndices.map(idx => numArray[idx]));
    }
    while (++i >= numArray.length) { // No more successor index available
        if (selectedIndices.length == 0) return allVariants; // All done
        i = selectedIndices.pop(); // Undo a previous selection
        number += numArray[i]; // Remove from sum
    }
    selectedIndices.push(i); // Select index and recur:
    return getNumberComponents(numArray, number - numArray[i], selectedIndices, allVariants);
}

console.log(getNumberComponents([7, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 8, 1], 8));
```